# Entry in notebook - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with input in a notebook in TKinter. The problem is in this to add Entry to not book I tried add Entry to root and to the notebook but still is not working, so here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Lizard Notebook")
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')
root.resizable(True, True)
root.minsize(400, 400)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(expand=True)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=1000, height=500)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=1000, height=500)

frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

notebook.add(frame1, text='Notebook')
notebook.add(frame2, text='Options')

entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it is added, just expand the window in height or reduce the height of the `Notebook`

Comment: It is because the root window is not big enough to show all the widgets.  Why do you create a 1000x500 notebook inside a 600x400 window?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if you want Entry inside notebook then Entry should use `notebook` or rather `frame1` instead of `root`

Comment: and first run it without `width`, `height` because your notebooks are too big and it can't display `Entry` in window - but if you resize window then you should see `Entry`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand but the code example is good and one solution is to change width and height of frame1 and frame2.

```
frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=600, height=352)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=600, height=352)
```

This places the entry tool beneath the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As @aws noted in the comment: you don't need `frameX.pack()` when you use `notebook.add(frameX, ...)`

---

If you want to display `Entry` inside `Notebook` then you should use `frame1` instead of `root`

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Lizard Notebook")
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')
root.resizable(True, True)
root.minsize(400, 400)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

notebook.add(frame1, text='Notebook')
notebook.add(frame2, text='Options')

entry = ttk.Entry(frame1, width=40)
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

If you want to display `Entry` below  `Notebook` then your `width`,`height` creates too big notebook and it uses all space in window and it can't display `Entry` - and you have to manually resize window to see `Entry`.

Better use `fill='both'` in

```
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
```

and it will automatically use all space but it will also display `Entry`.

---

```
mport tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Lizard Notebook")
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')
root.resizable(True, True)
root.minsize(400, 400)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

notebook.add(frame1, text='Notebook')
notebook.add(frame2, text='Options')

entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the two `frameX.pack(...)` are not necessary.

Comment: @acw1668 you are right. I will add this information to answer.